# Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea

I am getting the below error when I run my program.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Out1\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20190605185814_0005_m_000000_3\part-00000
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1133)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1070)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:960)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1489)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1468)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1468)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1468)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at KafkaFile.BinaryConsumerFile.main(BinaryConsumerFile.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Out1\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20190605185814_0005_m_000000_3\part-00000
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1133)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using IntelliJ IDE and have added the below info in pom.xml.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

It has downloaded all the dependencies. 
I tried google but could not find a similar issue, found similar error but not exactly this one.

Below is my code:

```
    public class ABC{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            //Create a SparkContext to initialize
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Word Count");

            // Create a Java version of the Spark Context
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

            // Load the text into a Spark RDD, which is a distributed representation of each line of text
            JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("C:\\wordlist.txt");
            JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile
                    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("[ ,]")).iterator())
                    .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
                    .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
            counts.foreach(p -> System.out.println(p));
            System.out.println("Total words: " + counts.count());
            counts.saveAsTextFile("C:\\Out1");
        }

    }
```

I would need help to solve this issue. Also as a second question, by any chance can I use same directory for saveAsTextFile if I run the program more than once. Basically I would need to save the files in a single directory. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to collect data from "`Counts`" `RDD` as `Counts.collect` instead of `saveAsTextfile` (just to debug issue).

It seems like you are writing `null` to the text file. if it return any value then check your spark write permission at your local path `C:\\Out1`.

Comment: Hi Nikk, Tried that, got below error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
 at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:443)
 at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
 at

Comment: However for the line, counts.foreach(p -> System.out.println(p));

I am getting below output prior to this error.

(a,2)
(casd,1)
(as,4)
(fasf,1)
(vas,2)
(aeas,1)
Total words: 6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException